# How to perform backend data translation using i18next without having backend data translations in json translation file?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, translation, i18next, react-i18next

I have a database in which the users dynamically enter data in English. I need to translate that in to another language when it is displayed on the frontend. For the static data on the frontend like the buttons and static text I can create translation files and add their translations but the problem is that for the backend data I don't know what the user is going to enter in the database which is why I cannot create a translation for that text before hand in the json translation file.

Any help on how I can auto translate text for which no translation is provided in the json translation file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an external service, like [Google's](https://cloud.google.com/translate) or any other you find. [Here](https://www.abstractapi.com/guides/best-translation-apis-for-developers) is a list of a few other services: